# Losing reference to NSWindows in AppDelegate

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

I'm running into issues where I lose reference to NSWindows that are declared in AppDelegate, with the code below.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var window1: CustomWindow1!
    var window2: CustomWindow2!

    func setupWindows() {
        self.window1 = CustomWindow1()
        self.window2 = CustomWindow2()
        let vc2 = VIEWOFSOMEVIEWCONTROLLER()
        self.window2.contentView.addSubview(vc2.view)
        self.window1.grandchildVC = vc2
        self.window1.addChildWindow(self.window2!, ordered: NSWindowOrderingMode.Above)
        // etc.
    }

    @IBAction addWindowsAgain(sender: AnyObject) {
        // This is where if fails
        if self.window1 != nil {
            self.window1 == nil
        }
    }
}

class CustomWindow1() {
    var grandchildVC: NSViewController
    func deleteChildWindowThenSelf() {
        self.grandchildVC.view.window.close()
        self.close()
    }
}
```

I am able to call `deleteChildWindowThenSelf()`, and get rid of the windows as expected, but when calling `addWindowsAgain` in AppDelegate, if fails with `lldb` error. Does AppDelegate lose those window vars when `close` is called, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: There are several things wrong with your code. First of all, your window1 and window2 variables should be optionals, since they don't get initialized with the class, and you will indeed be setting their value to nil. -- Also, your CustomWindow1 isn't a subclass of anything, you probably want it to be a subclass of NSWindow, or NSWindowController. Typically, you initialize an NSWindowController and keep a reference to that, rather than its window.

Comment: @ElmerCat Thanks for pointing out that it should be an optional. Second, sorry, I forgot to write what I subclassed. Yes, it is subclassing NSWindow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSWindow` has a variable `releasedWhenClosed` which is `true` by default for custom created windows unless the window is owned by a window controller.

Set the variable to `false`.

Comment: thanks. But when I reinitialize the windows after closing them, there seems to be multiple instances of that window, despite setting those windows to nil after close.