# Proper way to reuse NSWindowControllers

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345701/losing-reference-to-nswindows-in-appdelegate).

I'm trying to create an app with a few windows that pop up on start,
and can be closed ,then opened again later.

I'm not having issues with reopening the windows anymore,
but issues with memory. It keeps going up, everytime I request those windows to show again.

Here is my code:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var parentWC: NSWindowController?
    var childWC: NSWindowController?

    func showThem() {
        if self.parentWC == nil {
            let parentWindow = CustomWindow()
            self.parentWC.window = parentWindow
        }
        if self.childWC == nil {
            let childWindow = NSWindow()
            self.childWC.window = childWindow
            self.parentWC.window.addChildWindow(self.childWC.window)
        }
    }

    func closeAllWindows() {
        self.childWC.window.close()
        self.parentWC.window.close()
    }

    // From app menu
    @IBAction func showThemAgain(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.parentWindow.window = nil
        self.parentWC = nil
        self.childWindow.window = nil
        self.childWC = nil
        self.showThem()
    }
}

class CustomWindow: NSWindow {
    func onCloseRequest() {
          let appD = (NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate) as! AppDelegate
          appD.closeAllWindows()
    }
}
```

If I'm closing the windows and settings the vars to nil, what is causing the memory usage to go up every time I show these windows? Are they not being closed?

*Note that there is a button in CustomWindow that is used for closing.

Comment: Generally you have two ways to this. Reopen the same window. Or create a new one. If it's truly the same window, just instantiate the first time you show it and keep a reference to it.

Comment: @uchuugaka Thanks. How would you reopen a window?

Comment: "Closing" (ordering out) a window doesn't mean the memory for the window/controller is release.

Comment: @Wevah So how would I release them?

Comment: Have you checked with Instruments already? What does it say?

Comment: @ATV The contentViews of the windows seem to be leaking, so I'm trying to nil out everything in them before setting the window and windowcontroller to nil, but still getting them.

Comment: So I guess my question would be, when window is closing, are the contents being released? Or are they staying? Could this be the reason behind constant memory increase?

Comment: Look for strong references to views and or view controllers

Comment: Try to removeChild window (assign nil to array holding them) before you assign nil to window